# How to do full stack integration testing of web applications

Tags: ruby, tdd, selenium, bdd, culerity

I'm looking to enhance our current test suites, and continuous integration builds with full stack integration/acceptance testing.

I'm looking into tools like Culerity and Selenium that can execute front end javascript while running user stories.  I'm looking for something that can provide coverage of front-end javascript and high level features without sucking up tons of development time maintaining a complex test environment. We're currently using Rspec, Cucumber, and CruiseControl.rb, so easy integration with those tools would be ideal.

Are any of the headless browsers and js-capable test environments to a point where they are worth the trouble of setting up and maintaining?  What are the best option you've come across, and pitfalls to avoid?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You sound like you are way further down this road than I am, but I'll comment anyway.

I am working on a JavaScript project (with a Java + MySQL back end) and decided to use Selenium for testing, and to try to achieve as thorough coverage as I could. I also poked around with a few other testing tools, but I can't say I really got to know any of them. None of them appeared, from their web sites, to be very polished or popular compared to Selenium. I am planning to integrate to CruiseControl eventually, but haven't done so yet.

This has been an interesting project and at the end of the day, I am quite happy with Selenium. Selenium plusses:

1. Test 'scripts' can all be written in Java, no obscure scripting language involved. Among other things, you can easily do things like manipulate and verify the data in your database before and after tests.
2. Se also supports Perl, C#, etc. I think, although that is of no interest to me.
3. Selenium IDE is a great tool for quickly understanding how Se works, how locators work, etc. You don't want to actually run tests long-term using the IDE, but it's great for getting your feet wet, and for ongoing figuring things out.
4. Se seems to work flawlessly with jUnit. Probably TestNG as well, but have not tried that yet, it's on my todo list.
5. Excellent documentation and web site.

Minuses:

1. I spent a LOT of time figuring out how to locate elements in all cases. This is partially the 'fault' of the framework I am using (ExtJS), not Selenium.
2. It seems no matter what you do, Se has timing dependencies - eg. places where you have to inject artificial pauses to make it work.
3. There are also monitor-size dependencies in my tests. I think this is extremely undesirable but in some places it seems to be unavoidable. Basically, this is because there are many element types that JS doesn't support you clicking on programatically.
4. Related to #3, in places I am forced to drive the mouse. That means you have to have a dedicated test PC. Which is no big deal, but doesn't seem right.
5. Tests are slow - mainly due to the time it takes Se to invoke Firefox. No doubt this is partially my environment, and I suspect I could do lots of things to improve this. However, it is really noticeable and not obvious why. It takes about 10 minutes to run about 40 tests.
6. Support forum is very spotty. Well, you get what you pay for. But time and again I found someone had posted about my problem, and the post was ignored or else an invalid solution was offered with no follow-up when the OP pointed out that the suggestion was bogus.

HTH, cheers.